# "Taking on a Challenge in SPARK Ada" - Sum ghost function in post-condition having unintended behavior

Tags: ada, gnat, spark-ada, high-integrity-systems

I am writing a piece of software in SPARK Ada which requires the post-condition to verify that the function return value is equal to the summed values of an array. Upon proving the file where the function resides, I keep getting an error which doesn't quite add up, no pun intended (I will post screenshots of the code so as to allow a better look). The only acceptable values allowed in the array of size 10 are 0s or 1s.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @DeeDee can you help?

Comment: Screenshots *don’t* allow a better look. Pasting actual code as text does.

Comment: Hi @SimonWright, new around here. I'll bear that in mind next time. Best wishes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fix:

```
 function CalcST(eegR: in eegReadings) return Natural is 
  
  supT: Integer := eegR(eegR'First);
  
 begin
  
  -- Sums the number of ones in the array
  
  for Index in eegR'First + 1 .. eegR'Last  loop
     
     pragma Loop_Invariant -- 
       (supT = sumEEGR (eegR) (Index - 1));

     pragma Loop_Invariant -- additional loop invariant
       (supT <= Index - 1);
     
     if eegR(Index) = 1
       
       then supT := supT + eegR(Index);
        
     end if;
     
  end loop;
  
  return supT;
  
 end CalcST;
```

Answer (score 3):

In the example below (and opposed to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171268)), I separated the ghost function that computes the partial sum into a generic ghost package `SPARK_Fold`. From this package I use the ghost function `Sum_Acc` to proof the summation loop in `Calc_ST`. The package `Example` can be proven using GNAT CE 2020 with prove level set to 1.

*Credits for the underlying method: [AdaCore blog post](https://blog.adacore.com/taking-on-a-challenge-in-spark).*

**example.ads**

```
with SPARK_Fold;

package Example with SPARK_Mode is
 
   subtype EEG_Reading_Index is Integer range 0 .. Integer'Last - 1;   
   subtype EEG_Reading       is Integer range 0 .. 1;
   
   type EEG_Readings is array (EEG_Reading_Index range <>) of EEG_Reading;
     
   package Sum_EEG_Readings is
     new SPARK_Fold.Sum
       (Index_Type  => EEG_Reading_Index,
        Element_In  => EEG_Reading,
        List_Type   => EEG_Readings,
        Element_Out => Natural);
   
   function Calc_ST (EEG : EEG_Readings) return Natural with
     Pre  => EEG'Length > 0,
     Post => Calc_ST'Result = Sum_EEG_Readings.Sum_Acc (EEG) (EEG'Last);   

end Example;
```

**example.adb** (just computing the sum as usual here).

```
package body Example with SPARK_Mode is

   -------------
   -- Calc_ST --
   -------------
   
   function Calc_ST (EEG : EEG_Readings) return Natural is
      Result : Natural := EEG (EEG'First);
   begin      
      for I in EEG'First + 1 .. EEG'Last loop
         
         pragma Loop_Invariant
           (Result = Sum_EEG_Readings.Sum_Acc (EEG) (I - 1));
         
         Result := Result + EEG (I);
        
      end loop;      
      return Result;      
   end Calc_ST;

end Example;
```

**spark_fold.ads** (a generic helper package)

```
package SPARK_Fold with Ghost is
   
   --  Based on the blog post:
   --     https://blog.adacore.com/taking-on-a-challenge-in-spark
   
   ---------
   -- Sum --
   ---------
   
   generic
      type Index_Type  is range <>;
      type Element_In  is range <>;
      type List_Type   is array (Index_Type range <>) of Element_In;
      type Element_Out is range <>;
   package Sum with Ghost is
      
      type Partial_Sums is array (Index_Type range <>) of Element_Out;   
   
      function Sum_Acc (L : List_Type) return Partial_Sums with 
        Ghost,
        Pre  =>  (L'Length > 0),
        Post =>  (Sum_Acc'Result'Length = L'Length) 
        and then (Sum_Acc'Result'First  = L'First) 
        and then (for all I in L'First .. L'Last =>
                    abs (Sum_Acc'Result (I)) <= Element_Out (I - L'First + 1) * Element_Out (Element_In'Last))
        and then (Sum_Acc'Result (L'First) = Element_Out (L (L'First)))
        and then (for all I in L'First + 1 .. L'Last =>
                    Sum_Acc'Result (I) = Sum_Acc'Result (I - 1) + Element_Out (L (I)));
      
   end Sum;
   
   -----------
   -- Count --
   -----------
   
   generic
      type Index_Type is range <>;
      type Element    is range <>;
      type List_Type  is array (Index_Type range <>) of Element;
      with function Choose (X : Element) return Boolean;
      --  Count the number of elements for which Choose returns True.
   package Count with Ghost is
      
      type Partial_Counts is array (Index_Type range <>) of Natural;
      
      function Count_Acc (L : List_Type) return Partial_Counts with 
        Ghost,
        Pre  =>  (L'Length > 0),
        Post =>  (Count_Acc'Result'Length = L'Length)
        and then (Count_Acc'Result'First  = L'First)
        and then (for all I in L'First .. L'Last =>
                    Count_Acc'Result (I) <= Natural (I) - Natural (L'First) + 1) 
        and then (Count_Acc'Result (L'First) = (if Choose (L (L'First)) then 1 else 0)) 
        and then (for all I in L'First + 1 .. L'Last =>
                    Count_Acc'Result (I) = Count_Acc'Result (I - 1) + (if Choose (L (I)) then 1 else 0));
      
   end Count;

end SPARK_Fold;
```

**spark_fold.adb**

```
package body SPARK_Fold is

   ---------
   -- Sum --
   ---------
   
   package body Sum is
      
      function Sum_Acc (L : List_Type) return Partial_Sums is
         Result : Partial_Sums (L'Range) := (others => 0);
      begin
      
         Result (L'First) := Element_Out (L (L'First));
      
         for Index in L'First + 1 .. L'Last loop
      
            --  Head equal.
            pragma Loop_Invariant
              (Result (L'First) = Element_Out (L (L'First)));
         
            --  Tail equal.
            pragma Loop_Invariant
              (for all I in L'First + 1 .. Index - 1 =>
                 Result (I) = Result (I - 1) + Element_Out (L (I))); 
         
            --  Result within bounds.
            pragma Loop_Invariant
              (for all I in L'First .. Index - 1 =>
                  abs (Result (I)) <= Element_Out (I - L'First + 1) * Element_Out (Element_In'Last));
               
            Result (Index) := Result (Index - 1) + Element_Out (L (Index));
      
         end loop;
      
         return Result;
      
      end Sum_Acc;
      
   end Sum;
     
   -----------
   -- Count --
   -----------
     
   package body Count is
      
      function Count_Acc (L : List_Type) return Partial_Counts is
         Result : Partial_Counts (L'Range) := (others => 0);
      begin
      
         if Choose (L (L'First)) then
            Result (L'First) := 1;
         else
            Result (L'First) := 0;
         end if;
      
         for Index in L'First + 1 .. L'Last loop
      
            --  Head equal.
            pragma Loop_Invariant
              (Result (L'First) = (if Choose (L (L'First)) then 1 else 0));
         
            --  Tail equal.
            pragma Loop_Invariant
              (for all I in L'First + 1 .. Index - 1 =>
                 Result (I) = Result (I - 1) + (if Choose (L (I)) then 1 else 0)); 
         
            --  Bounds.
            pragma Loop_Invariant 
              (for all I in L'First .. Index - 1 =>
                 Result (I) <= Natural (I) - Natural (L'First) + 1);
               
            if Choose (L (Index)) then
               Result (Index) := Result (Index - 1) + 1;
            else
               Result (Index) := Result (Index - 1) + 0;
            end if;
               
         end loop;
      
         return Result;
      
      end Count_Acc;
      
   end Count;

end SPARK_Fold;
```

Comment: Hi @DeeDee :) My Bad! When looking at your solution I missed this "pragma Loop_Invariant
           (Result = Sum_Acc (L) (I - 1));" - this has fixed the issue I had. Thank you for your response anyhow! God bless :)